# Show dialog with a "Circle Loading Icon" in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygtk

My question is simple, i want to show a dialog with an animated circle like this
[image]

Is there a portable way to do this and without using .gif images?
NOTE: the image was an example, i want to use the one included in pygtk

Comment: Can you show us any working code you've put toward this problem of your own?

Comment: as the title says i want to show in a dialog, read please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Gtk.Spinner` if GTK is indeed what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use canvas http://thinkvitamin.com/code/how-to-draw-with-html-5-canvas/
But .gif is more painless way, i think.

Answer (score 0):

```
import os,time
blah = True #4 forever
l = ["|","/","-","\\"]
I = 0
while True:
    try:
        i = l[I]
    except IndexError:
        I = 0
        i = l[I]
    if not blah: #when to stop
        break
    print i
    time.sleep(.1) #delay before changing
    os.system('CLS') #clear screen
    I+=1
```

console loading icon